# Is there a way to configure min date in angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, datepicker, accessibility

In documentation of https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker I'm unable to find a configuration to set min date. I need to disable all past dates.

Comment: Seems there are closed issues from long ago and no updates anywhere to include this functionality. But there is some sample on how to implement it yourself: https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/200

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code.

```
import {DateButton} from 'angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker';
import * as _moment from 'moment';
import {unitOfTime} from 'moment';

private startDatePickerFilter(dateButton: DateButton, viewName: string): boolean {
   return dateButton.value >= moment().startOf(viewName as unitOfTime.StartOf).valueOf();
}
```

Reference : https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/components/DlDateTimePickerComponent.html#selectFilter and https://stackblitz.com/github/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-demo